# schedule notification in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I'm having problem to schedule notifications,
I have some notifications in laravel 5.3, the notifications are being queued using the ShouldQueue interface and and Queueable trait.
The problem is I want to send the notification between specific hours, the only option built in the notification feature is using the delay method.

How can i make custom schedule for the notifications that are being queued?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Laravel Sheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) for this. This will allow you to run certain code at specific moments, just like a cronjob. You can create your notifications in a scheduled task.

Comment: That will only work if the 'specific hours' are the same every day and will still need logic to read the jobs from somewhere. Just saying "Laravel Scheduling" is only one tool for part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

figured it out,

I`m calculating the current time in my server according to the target time in another time zone i want the notification to be fired using Carbon library.

after i have the target time that i want the notification to be fired i`m just adding delay to the notification with the carbon instance.